# Google drive API access with service account from PHP

Tags: php, google-api, google-drive-api

I have to uploaded files to Google Drive from my site. So I need to use google service account. I created it at Google Developer Console.

This is what I have so far:

```
    session_start();      

    define('DRIVE_SCOPE', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file');
    define('SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL', 'xxx@developer.gserviceaccount.com');
    define('SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PKCS12_FILE_PATH', 'xxx.p12');

    function buildService() {
        $key = file_get_contents(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PKCS12_FILE_PATH);
        $auth = new Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials(
            SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL,
            array(DRIVE_SCOPE),
            $key);
        $client = new Google_Client();

        $client->setAssertionCredentials($auth);
        return new Google_Service_Drive($client);
    }

    function uploadFile($service, $mime, $src) {            
        $file = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile();
        $file->setMimeType($mime);
        $data = file_get_contents($src);

        try {
            $createdFile = $service->files->insert($file,
                array(
                    'data' => $data,
                    'mimeType' => $mime,
                    'convert' => true,
                    'uploadType' => 'media'
                )
            );

            return $createdFile;
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            print "An error occurred: " . $e->getMessage();
        }
    }

    $service = buildService();
    uploadFile($service, "text/plain", "document.txt");
```

And I'm getting following errors:

> Notice: Undefined index: uploadType in D:\dvlp\projects\local\google_drive_api\Google\Service\Resource.php on line 212
>
> Notice: Undefined index: uploadType in D:\dvlp\projects\local\google_drive_api\Google\Service\Resource.php on line 212

**UPD** 
Added upload type. Error disappeared, but no files added to GDrive

Please help me.

Comment: A couple of observations. "So I need to use google service account" isn't strictly true. It depends if you want to upload to a service account or your own account, the two being very different. "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly" is an odd scope to use for Google Drive.

Comment: I came to use service account because it seems to me that it's much easier then using user's account Auth. Although i got a trouble using user authentication, it doesn't work for me at all.

Comment: @pinoyyid I updated my question. Please If you can help me somehow

Comment: If you aren't using the service account to upload the files remember it wont have access to the files.   A service account isn't you.    I don't see "uploadType " anywhere in your code so where exactly is the error coming from?

Comment: @Steve.B. Sorry I don't know php and don't use libraries, so I'm not much help. A word of advice is to make sure you understand what a service acount is, before trying to use it. A lot of people mistakenly assume it's an easier to implement OAuth mechanism for existing accounts. In fact it exists for a very specific purpose, namely to create a brand new Google Account owned by the app in place of a conventional user.

Comment: Having said that, a guess might be that the php library requires an uploadType parameter (multipart, resumable, etc)

Comment: @pinoyyid Thanks a lot for input. But I'm confused so much, because I can't get it to work at all. I can't find the order of thing what I should do. Say I got athorised... What's next? How to access to google drive?

Comment: Well I think you're a step closer. Some more observations ... I can't see you setting a title anywhere, so no idea what filename you're expecting to see. You need to ensure the mime type is correct. Specifically, it's the mime type of the source data. The documentation says that an uploadType of "media" is valid, but frankly it makes no sense. "media" means there is no meta-data, such as title, folder, etc. For a new file, you should be using either "multipart" or "resumable". It's always a good idea to figure out how to make the library dump the raw http request and response to a log file...

Comment: ... so you can compare what's on the wire with that Drive is expecting. Try Googling for an example of a php library upload as it's possible the Google documentation is out of date, eg. the fact that it appears that uploadType is now a mandatory parameter. Look at the multipart example from https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/guide/media_upload
Aaaargh I hate libraries.

Comment: In service account using Google-Drive Api , I'm not sure but I think problem is that you do not include any library for Google-Client drive API.